# LINQ check string property for NULL in generating a ToList()

Tags: c#, linq

I have this Linq statement which builds a list successfully if property isn't NULL

```
 results.AddRange(m_CTS.Entity.Where(x => x.Property.Contains(search)).ToList());
```

However, if x.property is null then it errors, so I would like to try to check it for null and if it isnt null, proceed in building the list.

I have tried,

```
 results.AddRange(m_CTS.Entity.Where(x => x.Property == null ? "" : x.Property.Contains(search)).ToList());
```

But this also errors, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What error are you getting from the second query?

Comment: Change `(x => x.Property == null ? ""` to `(x => x.Property == null ? false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x.Property.Contains(search)` returns a `bool` so your other side of the ternary operator should do that too:

```
x => x.Property == null ? false : x.Property.Contains(search)
```

Or simply:

```
x => x.Property != null && x.Property.Contains(search)
```

Answer (score 7):

You should just check for `null` like this:

```
x.Property != null && x.Property.Contains(search)
```

`Where` expects a statement that returns a `bool`, but your first expression returns `string` and other one returns `bool`.So it doesn't compile.

The reason why `&&` works because of [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit).If `x.Property != null` evalutes to false the second expression won't be evaluted and you won't get the exception.

Answer (score 1):

This may be you are looking

```
 class Persons
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var personCollection = new List<Persons>
            {
                new Persons {Id = 1, Name = "Manu"},
                new Persons {Id = 2, Name = "Lijo"},
                new Persons {Id = 3, Name = "John"},
                new Persons {Id = 4, Name = null},
                new Persons {Id = 5, Name = null},
            };

            List<string> personsNames =
                personCollection.Where(x => x.Name != null && x.Name.Contains("j")).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();


            foreach (var personame in personsNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(personame);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
results.AddRange(m_CTS.Entity.Where(x => x.Property != null && x.Property.Contains(search)).ToList());
```